# Count Fixnums in Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a function with an arbitrary number of arguments. My function looks like this:

```
sum(n, *rest)
```

How do I iterate through the array `rest` so that it will check if an argument is a `Fixnum`, sum it if it is, and do nothing otherwise? For example:

```
sum(5,1,2,k,D,3)
# => 6
```

Comment: You actually need just `Fixnum`s or maybe you would match any kind of [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Integer.html)?

Comment: If you wish to include `Bignum`'s, as @toro2k suggests, just change `Fixnum` to `Integer` in the answers below.  Want floats too?  Change `Fixnum` to `Numeric` (and leave the initial value for `reduce`--aka `inject`--the `Fixnum` zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way (though I prefer @Arup's use of `grep`):

```
a.group_by(&:class)[Fixnum].reduce(0,:+)

a = [1, :cat, 3, 'dog']
b = a.group_by(&:class) #=> {Fixnum=>[1,3],Symbol=>[:cat],String=>["dog"]}
c = b[Fixnum]           #=> [1,3]       
reduce(0,:+)            #=> 4
```

I have assumed that zero is to be returned if the array contains no Fixnums.  If, in that case, nil is to be returned, change `reduce(0,:+)` to `reduce(:+)`.

Answer (score 6):

Do as below :

```
ary = rest.grep(Fixnum)
# return the summation of the array elements, if array is not empty
# 0, when array is empty or contains only one element as `0`.
ary.reduce(0,:+)
```

Look [`#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) .

Examples :

```
ary = [1,"2",{1 => 2 },8]
ary.grep(Fixnum).inject(0,:+) # => 9
ary = ["2",{1 => 2 },(1..2)]
ary.grep(Fixnum).inject(0,:+) # => 0

# counting the how many Fixnums are there
ary = [1,"2",{1 => 2 },8]
ary.grep(Fixnum).size # => 2
```

Comment: Will inject add arguments? And now do I need to put it in a loop?

Comment: @Fengson it will do addition

Comment: You are right, I missed that. One more reason to return `0` for the empty array.

Comment: One last thing - how to I count how many arguments are Fixnums in that array? like length but only Fixnums.

Comment: @Fengson Just `ary.size`, as after using `grep` method, it contains only Fixnum objects.. very simple :-) You can do `rest.grep(Fixnum).size`.

Comment: Thank you, I found my problem :)

Comment: +1 for use of the mighty [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep): `grep(pattern)` "Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern === element."